# Getting "Operation not permitted" or "Not a regular file" when uploading file with Python ftplib

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

I'm want to upload a file using Python to an rental FTP server (coreserver). The code is like this

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import ftplib

def ftp_upload(hostname, username, password, upload_src_path, upload_dst_path):
    ftp = ftplib.FTP(hostname)
    ftp.set_pasv("true")
    ftp.login(username, password)
    fp = open(upload_src_path, 'rb')
    ftp.storbinary(upload_dst_path ,fp)

    ftp.close()
    fp.close()

hostname = "example.com"
upload_src_path = "/content/drive/My Drive/DSC_0569.JPG"
upload_dst_path = "STOR /public_html/example.com/"
username = "example"
password = "example"

ftp_upload(hostname, username, password, upload_src_path, upload_dst_path)
```

but error happens like this

```
error_perm: 550 /public_html/example.com/: Operation not permitted
```

I tried

```
STOR /public_html/
STOR /public_html
STOR /public_html/example.com/
STOR /public_html/example.com
STOR /example.com/
STOR /example.com
```

but the error happens all the time

```
error_perm: 550 /public_html/example.com/: Operation not permitted
```

or

```
error_perm: 550 /public_html/example.com/: Not a regular file
```

Can anybody help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The path in [`FTP.storbinary`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.storbinary) argument is the path to the target file, not only to the destination folder. *How else would ftplib know the name of the file you are uploading?*

So it should be:

```
upload_dst_path = "STOR /public_html/xxxxxxx.com/DSC_0569.JPG"
```

Answer (score -1):

Turns out C# doesn't support CWD command <=4.0, and the solutionMmicrosoft gave was a function named SetMethodRequiresCWD() which gives a NullReferenceException. So i had to use a custom library named AlexFTPS, here is the code:

```
FTPSClient client = new FTPSClient())
{
client.Connect(host,
new NetworkCredential(username, password), 
ESSLSupportMode.ClearText //For without SSL/TSL
);
client.SetCurrentDirectory("usbfolder");
client.PutFile(filePath,fileName); // "C:/file.txt" and "file.txt", for example
}
```

I'm putting this here in hope that nobody else goes through this pain.

Comment: The question is neither about C# nor about CWD.